InverseLaplaceTransform returns the input
Initially, I was trying to invert the following expression:
$$ \frac{e^{-a\sqrt s}}{s-c} $$ and got the following result:
InverseLaplaceTransform[E^(-a Sqrt[s])/(s - c), s, t]
(* ConditionalExpression[1/2 E^(-a Sqrt[c] + c t) (Erfc[(a - 2 Sqrt[c] t)/(2 Sqrt[t])] + 
    E^(2 a Sqrt[c]) Erfc[(a + 2 Sqrt[c] t)/(2 Sqrt[t])]), a > 0] *)

Then, I coded this expression in Python for other purposes in which $c$ was negative. I thought we would just ignore the imaginary part generated due to this and take the real part as our answer. But, I was getting wrong values. (Should have been in range of 10 but is in order of $10^4$)
So I checked it with Mathematica, but I don't get the result:
InverseLaplaceTransform[E^(-a Sqrt[s])/(s + c), s, t]
(* InverseLaplaceTransform[E^(-a Sqrt[s])/(c + s), s, t] *)

Am I doing something wrong here?

Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please use E instead of e and observe proper syntax. This function is present under the Neat Examples on the doc page.

The question has been edited. Pls look @Syed

Domen has edited the question. Could you now look at it? @Syed

I am on v12.2 on Win7-x64 and I see this. What $Version are you on?

I am on v13.3.1 on Win10-x64

$Version

"14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)"

Clear["Global`*"]

ilt1 = InverseLaplaceTransform[E^(-a  Sqrt[s])/(s - c), s, t]


InverseLaplaceTransform[E^(-a  Sqrt[s])/(s + c), s, t]

(* InverseLaplaceTransform[E^(-a Sqrt[s])/(c + s), s, t] *)

Include assumptions
ilt2 = Assuming[a > 0 && c > 0,
  InverseLaplaceTransform[E^(-a  Sqrt[s])/(s + c), s, t] // Simplify]

(* 1/2 E^(-I a Sqrt[c] - 
  c t) (Erfc[(a - 2 I Sqrt[c] t)/(2 Sqrt[t])] + 
   E^(2 I a Sqrt[c]) Erfc[(a + 2 I Sqrt[c] t)/(2 Sqrt[t])]) *)

(ilt1 /. c -> -c) == ilt2 // FullSimplify[#, a > 0 && c > 0] &

(* True *)


A trick:
InverseLaplaceTransform[
InverseLaplaceTransform[
LaplaceTransform[E^(-a*Sqrt[s])/(s + c), a, q] // Apart,
s, t] // Simplify // Expand, q, a] // FullSimplify

(* 1/2 E^(-I a Sqrt[c] - c t) (Erfc[(a - 2 I Sqrt[c] t)/(2 Sqrt[t])] + 
   E^(2 I a Sqrt[c])  Erfc[(a + 2 I Sqrt[c] t)/(2 Sqrt[t])])*)


Of course, your Code does show the expected answer in Mathematica, but the point is why exactly a simple line doesn't work.       (I don't know what the expressions 'Apart' , 'Expand' are and how they are used

@KNVCSG We ordinary users don't have much influence as it was programmed by the creators of Wolfram Mathematica. So you ask why it doesn't work, that's not my question.
